# How to read floating points from terminal? scanf always gets 0.0

Tags: c, floating-point, double, scanf

```
int main(){

    double N = 0;
    char unit[10];
    printf("Insert float > ");
    scanf("%f%s",&N,unit);
    printf("\n\n%f\n\n",N);

}
```

So in the terminal:

```
Insert float > 0.2hz
```

output:

```
0.000000hz
```

How could I save in N value the correct 0.2 value?

Comment: `N` is a `double`, not a `float`.

Comment: Please compile your code using a basic set of compilation flags to catch simple errors like this -- any decent compiler will warn you about this. See your compiler's documentation (e.g. for [`gcc`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html), you might use `gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra program.c`). Also, please get familiar with the documentation for `printf` and in particular, the correct format specifiers to use.

Comment: `%f` -> `%lf` should do the job

Comment: That cannot possibly be the actual output of your code

Comment: @klutt true, it doesn't print `unit`, but the OP could be running a different version (which often happens on SO..)

Comment: Side note: **always check the return value of `scanf`** -- its very important.